# Unable to create file sys_get_temp_dir()

Tags: php, codeigniter

During the execution of a project in PHP ( CodeIgniter ) I get this error.

It corresponds to that line of code in the file Session_files_driver.php of CodeIgniter.

Previously I worked on Linux, but since I passed under W10, I get this error.

Thanks for your help.

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: touch(): Unable to create file
>   sys_get_temp_dir()\ci_sessionc1e70147453a4c2aa17523a19927bce80ef4afe9
>   because No such file or directory
>
> Filename: drivers/Session_files_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 234
>
> Backtrace:

```
if (($this->_file_handle = fopen($this->_file_path.$session_id, 'w+b')) === FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you've provided `'sys_get_temp_dir()'` as a string (note the quotes) for your *sess_save_path* value. It's a function, you're not supposed to put quotes around it.

Also, it's a bad idea to use the system-wide temporary directory for your session files' location. That directory is readable by everybody, which means that any other user on the system can read your users' session data - you must avoid that!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely a write permission error. Grant apache user the permission to write to disk.